# Fails to iterate through a loop - python Flask server

Tags: python, list, request

I'm trying to iterate through a list object in python. I'm uploading two files and retrieving it through `request.files.getlist("file")` call. Here is the code below I used:

**Edit**

```
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file")
        print uploaded_files,type(uploaded_files)
        for f in request.files.getlist("file"):
            print request.files.getlist,type(uploaded_files)
            if f and allowed_file(f.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
                f.save(os.path.join('images/', filename))
        return "Success"
    return "Failed to upload"
```

Below is the output I get for uploaded_files variable.

```
[] <type 'list'>
```

When I tried the following line:

```
 print request.files.getlist
```

I get:

```
<bound method ImmutableMultiDict.getlist of ImmutableMultiDict([('frontCheck',   <FileStorage: u'1_23_f.jpg' ('application/octet-stream')>), ('rearCheck', <FileStorage: u'1_23_r.jpg' ('application/octet-stream')>)])>
```

It doesn't iterate through the list as expected in for 'f in uploaded_files:'

Comment: how do you assert this?

Comment: `print request.files.getlist,type(uploaded_files)` - you are printing the function, not the value returned when calling the function - `print request.files.getlist("file"), type(uploaded_files)`, or better yet, just print the value of your variable: `print uploaded_files, type(uploaded_files)`.

Comment: It appears that `request.files.getlist("file")` is returning an empty list, so your program is working as expected. You will need to show more code for anyone to be able to say why it is doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at `help(flask.Request.files)`:

```
Each key in :attr:`files` is the name from the
``<input type="file" name="">``
```

and at `help(werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist)`:

```
Return the list of items for a given key. If that key is not in the
`MultiDict`, the return value will be an empty list.
```

So: you are specifying the wrong key `"file"`; you should instead be using `"frontCheck"` and `"rearCheck"`.

Comment: While a solution to the problem he is having while debugging, this is not an answer to the core question asked.

Comment: @Lattyware: how's this?

Answer (score -2):

Because you return inside the iteration. The function ends as soon as the return statement is reached.

Comment: That appears to be intended behaviour, and not an answer to the poster's problem.

Comment: I can't see you can possibly tell that from the question.

Comment: Because the issue the poster has is that 'it doesn't iterate through the list' - and the debug output he has given shows it's an empty list. If the problem was the return, it would have at least done one iteration. Also, the function name `upload_file()` implies an intent to upload a single file, making a return on the first save make sense.